# How to install latest gputils?

Tags: software-compilation

I'm trying to compile C for a PIC16F using SDCC on the RPi. It's going slow but I hope that installing an up to date version of gputils [as per here](https://sourceforge.net/p/piklab/discussion/633023/thread/a76d7da1/) will help.

So how do I do that? I previously installed gputils simply by apt-get (Stretch, RPi 2). I can't work out how to tell what version it installed. Do I need to compile it? Or will some binary be what I want? Please assume minimal Linux competence!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the installed version of a package with `dpkg -l [package name]`, or just search on the Internet for the package name along with "Raspbian Stretch"; you'll usually find [packages.debian.org](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/gputils) pretty high in the results which tells you the version available in the repository.

For Stretch, the available package is `1.4.0-0.1+b1`, which is far more recent than the version mentioned in the thread you linked, `0.13.4-beta` (which is to be expected, as that issue was posted in 2007, and it's been 11 years since that page was updated!).

That said, there is a "new" release of gputils, according to the [project website](https://gputils.sourceforge.io/); version 1.5.0 was released in August 2016. Curiously it appears no-one has bothered to package the latest version, but I doubt you'd need to update anyway, as your version is already *much* newer than the one listed in the linked thread.

If you're experiencing a similar error message, it may not be the same issue; it may be worth posting a new issue on their bug tracker, or perhaps asking here if relevant with the error message you get.